# Sqlite Update query data in database not updating java gui application

Tags: java, database, sqlite, user-interface

Guys i am trying to update data into my database I have already created insert and a delete option but after creating this update query my data is not being updating in database so i request for your help please help me  my problem is in video and tutorial available online the data is updating using an where statement in which they use a integer datatype but my database don't  have any integer field i have only string field and data is not being updated please help the code of update button is posted below `enter code here`

```
JButton ud_btn_Update = new JButton("Update");
        ud_btn_Update.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        ud_btn_Update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try { String query="update Customers set "
                        + "Name='"+ud_tf_Name.getText()+"' "
                        + ",Address='"+ud_tf_Address.getText()+"' "
                        + ",Gstin='"+ud_tf_Gstin.getText()+"' "
                        + ",Discount='"+ud_tf_Discount.getText()+"' "
                        + ",State='"+ud_tf_State.getText()+"' "
                        + ",StateCode='"+ud_tf_StateCode.getText()+"' "
                        + " where Name='"+ud_tf_Name.getText()+"' ";

                PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);  
                  pst.execute();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Updated!");
                  pst.close();
            } catch(Exception e4) {
                e4.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems syntactically correct and it should work if the table exists and the table and column names are not misspelled.
What may cause the code to not update the row in the table is the `where` clause.
 
This value:

```
ud_tf_Name.getText()
```

is obviously the new name that you want to replace the old value in the column `name`, right?
So, it does not exist in the table and the `where` clause does not return any row and nothing is updated.
You must save the old name in a string variable, say `oldname` and use it in the `where` clause:

```
............................................
 + " where Name='"+oldname+"' ";
```

Also you must learn to use [parameters with the prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to create safer code.

Comment: String oldvalue = ud_tf_Name.getText();

Comment: You must do this before the value inside ud_tf_Name is changed.

Comment: i understand what u mean to say is  so i tried it without updating the name coloum textfield  and it really worked but i also want to update the name colown so i tried this code but did not work  please see the code and help                                                                                                          String oldvalue = ud_tf_Name.getText();  where Name='"+oldvalue+"' @forpas

Comment: This line: `String oldvalue = ud_tf_Name.getText();` must not be inside `actionPerformed()` because then the name is already changed so you get the new value. You must put it in your code where you display the initial values of the row.

Comment: thank you it really helped but i find another way I  have a combo box in which i data from textfield is selected it show all other value in their respectfull value  so i update the code       where Name='"+comboBoxName.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'   so thank you very much dude you help me a lot being finding the answer from 3 days thank you @forpas